# Как обрабатывать капчу с помощью библиотеки vknet?

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vknet

Нужно перехватывать сообщение с ошибкой и выводить капчу в новом окне для ввода пользователем. Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При ошибке капчи в vknet предусмотрена ошибка *CaptchaNeededException* 
Сделать это можно примерно так:

```
try{
   /*Код, который вызывает исключение капчи*/
}
catch(VkNet.Exception.CaptchaNeededException cne){
   /*Вызываем окно, где выводим картинку капчи и куда вводим данные с картинки*/
   //cne.Img - Uri картинки
   //cne.Sid - Sid картинки (уникальный номер)
   //вызываем заново метод, вызвавший исключение, передав ему параметры Sid и значение капчи из картинки
}
```